# My wrapper never touches the bottom of the screen?

Tags: css

I've started coding a really simple layout I made sometime last year, I've finished most of it, when I discovered when the 'wrapper' div doesn't touch the bottom of the page, as if it has the "position: fixed" style on it, but it doesn't have that style. And I'm also stuck on why the Footer div isn't at the bottom, its right below the "topbar" div.
I'm really confused because I have no idea why  the footer and the wrapper divs aren't working properly ;(

I've published it to my site on the link below so you can check the html/css.
[HenryNorthen.com](http://henrynorthen.com/exp/softgreen/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that float consume no space in the layout; everything after your header is floating, so nothing's there to push the footer to the bottom.  Instead, the floating elements "float" away from the footer, which is placed right after the header.

If you add this to the style of your footer, it should solve this problem:

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my footer problem! Do you know how to fix the wrapper problem? :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by having a problem with the wrapper.

Comment: The wrapper div is the light gray background behind all the divs, if you resize the window, the bottom of the wrapper div never touches the bottom of the window, but I want it to **always** touch the bottom, so its fixed to the bottom, you should be able to see on the link I gave you on the main post

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the wrapper div to always be touching the footer? Take away the `bottom-margin` and `height: 100%` on the wrapper div and that should fix it.

Comment: That fixed it, but now the footer isn't at the bottom anymore, I've updated the site so you can see what I mean

Comment: Sorry I dunno why I said "bottom-margin" or where that even came from. What I meant to say is that you need to remove `padding-bottom: 150px` from the wrapper div as well. If you want the footer to always touch the bottom of the screen, you'll have to use something like [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer)

Comment: Damn why didn't I do that before... Thanks so much :)